# aws codebuild primary source webhook events (GitHub). How to set start build under these conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to get my codebuild to stop building when I make changes to my README.md file in GitHub but my FILE_PATH regex doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

How do I fix this so that when making changes to README.md codebuild simply ignores the change and doesn't build?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few things going on:

1. You might be getting multiple webhooks for the "same event" (similar to duplicate  GitHub Actions Workflows being triggered)

> If you specify multiple events, only one of those events needs to
> occur to trigger your workflow. If multiple triggering events for your
> workflow occur at the same time, multiple workflow runs will be
> triggered.
>
> [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-multiple-events)

This is most likely to happen when you push changes to the `README.md` file to a branch with an Open Merge Request, essentially triggering an event of type `PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED`.

Maybe try setting your event types to the following:

- `PUSH, PULL_REQUEST_CREATED, PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED`

2. The documentation seems contradictory in a few places on where `FILE_PATTERN` can be used. For example the [API Reference Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_WebhookFilter.html) has a *note* stating that it can be used in `PUSH` ****and**** `PULL_REQUEST` events but the [Boto3 Docs for codebuild.create_webhook](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codebuild.html#CodeBuild.Client.create_webhook) has a *note* saying it **only** works with `PULL_REQUEST` events.

3. If your codebuild project is also used as a build step in CodePipeline, that would trigger dual builds (see boto3 docs linked in 2):

> Warning If you enable webhooks for an CodeBuild project, and the
> project is used as a build step in CodePipeline, then two identical
> builds are created for each commit.

4. The regex for the filename might be incorrect (based on what i would try using cloudformation, console may handle it automatically)

   The CloudFormation equivalent of what you have in your console should be something like this:

```yaml
CodeBuildProject:
  Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
  Properties:
    Name: MyProject
    ServiceRole: service-role
    Artifacts:
      Type: NO_ARTIFACTS
    Environment:
      Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
      Image: aws/codebuild/standard:4.0
    Source:
      Type: GITHUB
      Location: source-location
    Triggers:
      Webhook: true
      BuildType: BUILD
      FilterGroups:
        # Filter Group 1
        #    is this  triggered when a webhook payload is of type 'PUSH'
        - - Type: EVENT
            Pattern: PUSH
          - Type: FILE_PATTERN
            # does the 'dot' need to be escaped '^README\.md$'? dot is 1 or more characters in cloudformation regex?
            # meaning the pattern is only looking for something like 'READMEX.md'
            #
            # ref cfn-docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html
            #   |_ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
            # 
            Pattern: ^README.md$ 
            ExcludeMatchedPattern: true
```

Does the output of the following aws-cli command match the filters defined in the Cloudfromation Example

```bash
# plz sanitize sensitive values if posting output
aws codebuild batch-get-projects --names MyProject
...
```